# SSL: how can i generate a CSR exportable to a .pfx in MMC?

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, pfx, csr

I have tried an online version, but that turned out to not be exportable.

can't get openssl to work on my only (windows) comp for some reason.

I can't find a linke to download IIS full - which presumably has an IIS manager with it. I can only get iisexpress to run.

How do i generate a CSR that I can export to a .pfx (using a private key) so that I can upload said .pfx to azure?

Thanks!

Comment: A few mistakes. 1) a CSR won't give you a PFX. 2) You don't need IIS or IIS Manager to create a CSR. OpenSSL is enough, so you just need to follow the guide, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs If there is any error with OpenSSL, show that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to download IIS from internet. It's already in your PC. You can turn it on by: Control Panel -> Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off. Check Internet Information Services to proceed installation:
[Install IIS on you PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVi7V.png)

Once you done CSR creation, you can submit it to certification provider so that you will get a pfx.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Install IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVi7V.png)
2. [Create CSR](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO21231)
3. Copy Txt and paste it into your certificate request
4. Complete the SSL certificate order
5. Compete the domain ownership verification by the supplier of the SSL
6. Supplier will email you a link to download PFX (if you are lucky), or they will email you a bunch of text starting with '---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--'
7. Paste that into a new text file, save as: cert.cer
8. [Import that into your certificate store](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO16588)
9. [Export the certificate as a PFX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx), choose a password ([keep it somewhere safe](http://keepass.info/download.html))